# Unable to send raw json data in post api data using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, api, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

Unable to send raw `JSON` data in `POST` api data using [Retrofit 2.0](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

```
try {
  JSONObject myUserData = new JSONObject();
  myUserData.put("mobile", "917023847899");
  myUserData.put("displayName", "Deepuu");
  myUserData.put("info", "AD");
  myUserData.put("photo", "");
  myUserData.put("displayName", "Deepu");

  JSONObject deviceData = new JSONObject();
  ;
  deviceData.put("deviceId", "2124578910556991");
  deviceData.put("pnToken", "klklklkl");
  deviceData.put("os", "android");
  deviceData.put("targetTopic", "jkjkjkjkj");

  myUserData.put("device", "" + deviceData);
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

  Api Ainterface = retrofit.create(Api.class);

  Call<Response> data = Ainterface.getResponse(myUserData);
  data.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        Response rr = response.body();
        Integer ss = rr.getStatusCode();
        Log.e("I Am", "Success"  );
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
      Log.e("I Am", "Failed");
    }
  });
```

MyInterface:

```
@POST("appUsers/")
Call<Response> getResponse(@Body RequestBody value);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for sending raw `JSON` data in `POST` api using `Retrofit 2.0`?  I'm new to using Retrofit; please help as I am getting `null` response in `onResponse` method.

Comment: add your Api and retrofit service generator class code too

Comment: the problem is i am not able to send these JSON object as perameters and getting null response .. :(

Comment: if you want to send json string without POJO Model class: [See this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332684/7048025)

Comment: if anyone want to send json string without POJO Model class: [See this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332684/7048025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GsonConverterFactory. So, you should pass model class object that is converted by retrofit to string and added to request body. But in your code, you passed JSONObject.

Create Model class as follows and change package name according your project structure:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Device {

@SerializedName("deviceId")
@Expose
private String deviceId;
@SerializedName("pnToken")
@Expose
private String pnToken;
@SerializedName("os")
@Expose
private String os;
@SerializedName("targetTopic")
@Expose
private String targetTopic;

/**
*
* @return
* The deviceId
*/
public String getDeviceId() {
return deviceId;
}

/**
*
* @param deviceId
* The deviceId
*/
public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The pnToken
*/
public String getPnToken() {
return pnToken;
}

/**
*
* @param pnToken
* The pnToken
*/
public void setPnToken(String pnToken) {
this.pnToken = pnToken;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The os
*/
public String getOs() {
return os;
}

/**
*
* @param os
* The os
*/
public void setOs(String os) {
this.os = os;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The targetTopic
*/
public String getTargetTopic() {
return targetTopic;
}

/**
*
* @param targetTopic
* The targetTopic
*/
public void setTargetTopic(String targetTopic) {
this.targetTopic = targetTopic;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Request.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Request {

@SerializedName("mobile")
@Expose
private String mobile;
@SerializedName("info")
@Expose
private String info;
@SerializedName("photo")
@Expose
private String photo;
@SerializedName("displayName")
@Expose
private String displayName;
@SerializedName("device")
@Expose
private Device device;

/**
*
* @return
* The mobile
*/
public String getMobile() {
return mobile;
}

/**
*
* @param mobile
* The mobile
*/
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
this.mobile = mobile;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The info
*/
public String getInfo() {
return info;
}

/**
*
* @param info
* The info
*/
public void setInfo(String info) {
this.info = info;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The photo
*/
public String getPhoto() {
return photo;
}

/**
*
* @param photo
* The photo
*/
public void setPhoto(String photo) {
this.photo = photo;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The displayName
*/
public String getDisplayName() {
return displayName;
}

/**
*
* @param displayName
* The displayName
*/
public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
this.displayName = displayName;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The device
*/
public Device getDevice() {
return device;
}

/**
*
* @param device
* The device
*/
public void setDevice(Device device) {
this.device = device;
}

}
```

And request of post as follows:

```
@POST("yourpath")
    Call<YourResponseModelClass> getResponse(@Body RequestModelClass request);
```

Update YourResponseModelClass & RequestModelClass according to your request and response model class.

You can generate model class from json, http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I dont understand .my api needs perameters to be passed as "raw" data and i have to pass a json object in tha .the only thing i wants to know is how can i do that . and if i pass a model class that how that will be passed as json object.

Comment: Thanks @USKMobility i got my reponse by using your approach .

Answer (score -1):

you can post raw jsonObject in retro 2.0. need to convert that into RequestBody like this

```
RequestBody requestBody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),myUserData.toString() );
Call<Response> data = Ainterface.getResponse(requestBody);
```

Comment: No effects on adding and removing this slash .